# Android layout problems with TextView and ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I just started coding a new application for Android and stumble over a warning.

> This tag and its children can be replaced by one  and a compound drawable

Another problem I have is the image placed on the right side. How can I do this without having trouble with layout_wight? See image ([2], yellow and green highlight).

I would like to follow the android [design guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqVU6.png) and prevent warnings. So how do I solve this? Actual my code looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTitleLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainTitleImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>


  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/mainTitleTextView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      android:paddingLeft="0dp"
      android:paddingRight="0dp"
      android:paddingTop="4dp"
      android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="2dp" android:background="#0099CC"></LinearLayout>
```

Do you guys know some good tutorials for building custom components so I do not get this error again or/and solve the placement problem?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqVU6.png) http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

[image]

Comment: You are a programmer you dont have to worry about warnings...:)

Comment: @himanshu: ignoring warning is not a good practice :D @burnersk: You can replace this layouts by using single `TextView` and with Compound Drawables.

Comment: yes, Agree with you @AdilSoomro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error, just an information (or a warning) that there is a more efficient way to achieve a row in the layout consisting of an image and a text view. You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/error_tab"
    />
```

The drawableLeft attribute adds the given drawable to the left of the text view. In a similar way you can place the image to the right.

However, you will not be able to fine tune the position of the image wrt. the text view.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. Do you have a hint for the right aligned image (the second problem)?

Comment: Ok, but without the compound drawables because of the image fine tune?

Comment: What do you mean by "compound drawable"? Do you have more than one image / drawable on the right?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post about compound drawables](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/815) which may help you in resolving your issues.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have had read your blog post before but can not solve my placement problem which Stefan has pointed out. But thank you anyway for your help.